# Permanent Residency for EU citizen

Tags: residency, passport

I have just submitted the application after more than 5 years residency in UK. I am required to send some documents together with the application including my passport. Do you know how long it takes to get the passport back from the Home Office? To note: I tried the Passpoort Return Service but it seems there are 4 weeks or more as waiting time and the documents must be sent within 10 days.

Answer (score 1):

For all I know you will get your passport back when your application is accepted or rejected, which will easily take three months, and quite possibly longer. I would try to call around if there is a place where you can use the passport return service earlier, even if it is in a less convenient location.

Comment: Other workarounds to consider: does the country of citizenship issue national ID cards, and are these sufficient for the applicant's needs while the application is in process?  If not, does the country of citizenship issue second passports?  Many do, although the current circumstances would not necessarily qualify in every country.